# how to get class property

Tags: c#

I have this method for convert object to collection.
I pass class as parameter object into this method

```
private NameValueCollection ObjectToCollection(object objects)
{
    NameValueCollection parameter = new NameValueCollection();

    Type type = objects.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        parameter.Add(property.Name.ToString(), property.GetValue(objects, null).ToString());
    }

    return parameter;
}
```

in this line

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
```

I get each public property such as

```
{System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncManager AsyncManager}
{System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker ActionInvoker}
{System.Web.HttpContextBase HttpContext}
.
.
.
```

I want just get property that I have written, no

```
{System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncManager AsyncManager}
{System.Web.Mvc.IActionInvoker ActionInvoker}
{System.Web.HttpContextBase HttpContext}
.
.
.
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want properties from the current type, i.e. not from base classes, do the following:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                BindingFlags.Public );
```

But, to get some additional flexibility, I would suggest using attributes to mark the properties you wish to include:

```
class Foo
{
    [Serializable]
    public string WeWantThis { get; set; }

    public string ButNotThis { get; set; }
}
```

Then, for each `PropertyInfo`, check whether it has that attribute applied to it or not with [PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getcustomattributes(v=vs.110).aspx). I used the built-in `SerializableAttribute` as an example, but you can of course roll your own attribute instead.

Comment: ,thank you for you'r help,i use this code PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties( BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly ); but i get  0 property.

Comment: @jon I missed a few BindingFlags there - see updated answer.